# Как показать кратчайший путь между двумя вершинами графа, найденный shortest_path() функцией из pygraph пакета?

Tags: python, graph

Необходимо вычислить кратчайший путь между двумя точками и показать его. Вычислить у меня получилось, а вот показать сам путь не могу.

```
from pygraph.classes.graph import graph
from pygraph.algorithms.searching import *

gr = graph()
gr.add_nodes(['A','B','C','X','Y','Z']) # Add nodes

# Add edges
gr.add_edge(('X','Y'), 2)
gr.add_edge(('X','Z'), 1)
gr.add_edge(('A','B'), 1)
gr.add_edge(('A','C'), 3)
gr.add_edge(('Y','B'), 4)
gr.add_edge(('Y','C'), 7)

sh1, sh2 = shortest_path(gr, source = 'X');

print(sh2['A']) #кратчайшее расстояние от X до A
```

> 7

Помимо числа 7 мне нужно получить что-то на подобии:

> X -> Y -> B -> A

Уверен что модуль [pygraph](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1823095/python-graph/docs/pygraph-module.html) позволяет это cделать, но не могу правильно сориентироваться - перелопатил весь модуль, но так и нашел что искал.

Answer (score 1):

На [этой](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1823095/python-graph/docs/pygraph.algorithms.minmax-module.html) странице описание функции shortest_path(graph, source).

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.